# Will it be replaced when redefining an existing filter in Springboot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When redefining an existing filter in the Spring boot, will the existing filter be replaced by the newly defined filter?
For example, if I redefine CorsFilter.class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:8080");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

}
```

Is org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter no longer used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter no longer used?

I think it's still used, you can have multiple filters.

To disable filter you can use `FilterRegistrationBean` (pass as an argument any `Filter` class which you want to disable)

```
@Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean(CorsFilter corsFilter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(corsFilter);
    filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
    return filterRegistrationBean;
  }
```

Comment: I debugged the org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.class and it was set to the value of CorsFilter that I set. Existing filters are still used, but only the settings have been changed.